# Convert lines in HTML to CSV

Tags: powershell, html-parsing

I have an html file with links in the format of

```
<a href="http://www.google.com>Date: 25.02.2013 10:30 Name: Google</a><br>
```

I'm trying to write a powershell script that will get the link, the date, time, and name and put them in CSV format (link,date,time,name)

the following will give me the link, but not the rest of the information, am I just missing something? the Regular Expressions work, although it would be helpful to ditch the "Name:" in the one looking for the name.

```
$input_path = 'C:\temp\myfile.html'
$output_file = 'C:\temp\myfile.csv'
$regex_link = '([a-zA-Z]{4})://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)’
$regex_date = '\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}'
$regex_time = '\d{2}:\d{2}'
$regex_name = 'Name:\s([\w]*)'
$myVar = select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex_link, $regex_date, $regex_time, $regex_name -AllMatches| % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } 
$myVar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the cleanest solution I guess, but it works in my test:

```
$input_path = 'C:\temp\myfile.html'
$output_file = 'C:\temp\myfile.csv'

(Get-Content $input_path) -match "href" | % {
$data = ($_ -replace '(?:.*)href="(.*?)">Date:\s*([\w\.]+)\s*([\w\:]+)\s*Name:\s*(.*)</a>(?:.*)' , '$1;$2;$3;$4').Split(";")
New-Object psobject -Property @{
    "Link" = $data[0].Trim()
    "Date" = $data[1].Trim()
    "Time" = $data[2].Trim()
    "Name" = $data[3].Trim()
    }
} | Select-Object Link, Date, Time, Name | Export-Csv $output_file -NoTypeInformation
```

Myfile.html:

```
<html>
<body>
asdsanfkj
djaksl
sadjklas
<a href="http://www.google.com">Date: 25.02.2013 10:30 Name: Googledas adka kasjiw</a><br>
sadsadmdsa
<a href="http://www.google2.com">Date: 22.22.2222 20:20 Name: Google2asd addasd </a><br>
sajl
dasjdsa
asd
</body>
</html>
```

Myfile.csv:

```
"Link","Date","Time","Name"
"http://www.google.com","25.02.2013","10:30","Googledas adka kasjiw"
"http://www.google2.com","22.22.2222","20:20","Google2asd addasd"
```

Comment: here's what i get in the output file after running your code.
`"Link","Date","Time","Name"
"True",,,`

Comment: The code executes well on PS2.0 See updated answer with my "sample" and result. If it doesn't work, you should provide a bigger sample(preferably complete html file with sensitive data removed/replaced). If you provide a complete sample, remember to not replace special characters if there are any.

Comment: I'm a dork, I forgot the file is generated with no line feeds, running your code after replacing the `<br>` with `<br>\n` provides the desired result...you're a star! Thank you!